# Spark Job keeps failing by the running the same map 3 times

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, dataframe, hadoop-yarn

My job has a step where I am converting the data frame as RDD[(key, value)] but the step runs three 3 times and getting stuck in the third time and fails

Spark UI shows :

Active Jobs(1)

```
  Job Id (Job Group)      Description    Submitted  Duration    Stages: Succeeded/Total Tasks (for all stages): Succeeded/Total

    3 (zeppelin-20161017-005442_839671900)   Zeppelin map at <console>:69      2016/10/25 05:50:02  1.6 min     0/1      210/45623
```

Completed Jobs (2)

```
  2 (zeppelin-20161017-005442_839671900)    Zeppelin map at <console>:69    2016/10/25 05:16:28     23 min  1/1       46742/46075 (21 failed)
  1 (zeppelin-20161017-005442_839671900)    Zeppelin map at <console>:69    2016/10/25 04:47:58     17 min  1/1        47369/46795 (20 failed)
```

This is the code :

```
 val eventsRDD = eventsDF.map {

      r =>
        val customerId = r.getAs[String]("customerId")
        val itemId = r.getAs[String]("itemId")
        val countryId = r.getAs[Long]("countryId").toInt
        val timeStamp = r.getAs[String]("eventTimestamp")

        val totalRent = r.getAs[Int]("totalRent")
        val totalPurchase = r.getAs[Int]("totalPurchase")
        val totalProfit = r.getAs[Int]("totalProfit")

        val store = r.getAs[String]("store")
        val itemName = r.getAs[String]("itemName")

        val itemName = if (itemName.size > 0 && itemName.nonEmpty && itemName != null ) itemName else "NA"


        (itemId, (customerId, countryId, timeStamp, totalRent, totalProfit, totalPurchase, store,itemName ))



    }
```

Can someone tell what is wrong here ? If I want persist/cache which one I should do ?

Error :

```
16/10/25 23:28:55 INFO YarnClientSchedulerBackend: Asked to remove non-existent executor 181
16/10/25 23:28:55 WARN YarnSchedulerBackend$YarnSchedulerEndpoint: Container marked as failed: container_1477415847345_0005_02_031011 on host: ip-172-31-14-104.ec2.internal. Exit status: 52. Diagnostics: Exception from container-launch.
Container id: container_1477415847345_0005_02_031011
Exit code: 52
Stack trace: ExitCodeException exitCode=52:
                at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:545)
                at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:456)
                at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:722)
                at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.launchContainer(DefaultContainerExecutor.java:211)
                at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:302)
                at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:82)
                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: your code doesn't compile - `itemName > 0` tries to compare a String and an Int.

Comment: @TzachZohar Sorry that was a typo in here. I have size comparison

Answer (score 0):

You map operation is resulting in some error and that propogates to the driver which results in task failure.

By default [spark.task.maxFailures](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#scheduling) has value as 4 which is for :

> Number of failures of any particular task before giving up on the job.
>   The total number of failures spread across different tasks will not
>   cause the job to fail; a particular task has to fail this number of
>   attempts. Should be greater than or equal to 1. Number of allowed
>   retries = this value - 1.

So what happens when your task fails spark tries to recompute the map operation untill it has failed 4 times in all.

**If I want persist/cache which one I should do ?**
[cache](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD@cache():RDD.this.type) is just specific persist operation where [RDD](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD) is persisted with default storage level (MEMORY_ONLY).

Comment: But I am not sure why it fails to compute this map.

Comment: you can check logs, check for error in both worker and driver logs.